# Post DOM array to controller in ASP.NET MVC5

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I am having issues taking a HTML DOM array and passing it to the controller using an ajax call.

This is how the post occurs (on a button click):

```
function onSaveMapClicked() {
    $.ajax({
        traditional: true,
        type: "POST",
        url: "/WaferMapper/SaveMap",
        contentType: "application/json",
        data: JSON.stringify(map.children),
        success: function (data) { },
        error: function (response) { alert(response); },
    });
}
```

This is the controller code that should handle this post:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult SaveMap(string mapData)
{
    return View();
}
```

So nothing is really happening yet here; I put in a breakpoint to see if I can hit it and I cannot.

Here is an example of how the array is populated:

```
for (var col = 1; col <= cols + 1; col++) {
    for (var row = 1; row <= rows + 1; row++) {
        var isPrintElement = row != 1 && col != 1;
        var elementColor = isPrintElement ? '#ffffff' : '#000000';
        this.children.push({
            color: elementColor,
            color_cache: elementColor,
            content: row == 1 ? col - 1 : col == 1 ? row - 1 : "",
            isPrint: isPrintElement,
            mask: "n/a",
            modifier1: new Modifier(""),
            modifier2: new Modifier(""),
            modifier3: new Modifier(""),
            modifier4: new Modifier(""),
            modifier5: new Modifier(""),
            modifier6: new Modifier(""),
            hasModifier: function () {
                return (this.modifier1.value != "" ||
                    this.modifier2.value != "" ||
                    this.modifier3.value != "" ||
                    this.modifier4.value != "" ||
                    this.modifier5.value != "" ||
                    this.modifier6.value != "");
            },
            width: width,
            height: height,
            top: row * (height + this.PRINT_MARGIN),
            left: col * (width + this.PRINT_MARGIN)
        });
    }
}
```

I know others have had this issue but looking at the other related posts here I still am unable to get this to work correctly.

I keep getting these errors when I click the 'Save Map' button:

```
POST http://localhost:xxxxx/WaferMapper/SaveMap 500 (Internal Server Error)
```

Comment: Did you try to debug the Controller and get more info on what caused the 500 error?

Comment: I tried by putting a breakpoint in the only line of code inside the 'SaveMap' method but the breakpoint never hits.  Any suggestions?

Comment: change `data: JSON.stringify(map.children),` to `data: {mapData:JSON.stringify(map.children)},`

Comment: @RobertMcKee I tried that and I still get the same internal server error.

Comment: why is `traditional:true` if you are sending json? Have you inspected the actual request to see if what is sent is what is expected? Really not much troubleshooting information here to work from

Comment: @charlietfl I did that because it seemed like the JSON.stringify call was doing weird things to the data.  I just tried removing that line and I still get the same error.

Comment: Try changing `data:` to `data: {mapData: "test" },` (and keep traditional: true removed, you don't need that)

Comment: My guess is that it is having a hard time deserializing your JSON object, possibly either array related, or that it is having a hard time deserializing however your modifiers are being serialized.

Comment: @RobertMcKee Should I implement .toJSON() on map.children since it is a custom object array?

Comment: You might need to depending on how it's getting serialized (or reorganize your object before serialization), IF that is the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Robert McKee for the help,

The trick was to implement a toJSON() method on the map object.

Here is my basic implementation (much more has to be done; I simply packaged the first two properties of the map object into a JSON object, in the end all properties will have to be a part of the JSON structure):

```
var WaferMap = function (canvas) {
    ....
    ....
}
WaferMap.prototype = {
    ....
    ....
    toJSON: function () {
        var json = "[";
        for (var i = 0; i < this.children.length; i++) {
            var element = this.children[i];
            json += "{" +
                "\"color:\"" + element.color + "\"," +
                "\"color_cache:\"" + element.color_cache + "\"},";
        }
        return json.substring(0, json.length - 1) + "];"
    }
}
```

Now this JSON string posts back correctly to the controller.

Here is the updated AJAX call:

```
function onSaveMapClicked() {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/WaferMapper/SaveMap",
        contentType: "application/json",
        data: {mapData:JSON.stringify(map)},
        success: function (data) { },
        error: function (response) {
            alert(response);
        }
    });
 }
```

Answer (score -1):

I'm not an expert, but I think it because there is no model binding happending, and your controller is expecting a string, and not a json object.

Bind your object to a model, and pass that back to your controller.

Also, I think if you remove:

```
contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
```

It will now post as a string, and should hit your controller.